# ROS Answers SE migration: rospy nodes

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rospy API [docs](http://ros.org/doc/api/rospy/html/) have a list of modules that are part of the rospy library. For someone wanting to write nodes using rospy, which modules in the api docs should he/she be concerned with. The reason I ask is that some of those modules are marked internal only. Does that mean people writing nodes need not be concerned with them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28272/rospy-nodes/) by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2012-02-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For writing a rospy node, the best documentation of the rospy API is the [rospy overview](http://ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview).

The most commonly used rospy functionality is documented there. In general, I would suggest only looking at the [autogenerated API docs](http://ros.org/doc/api/rospy/html/) if you can't find what you are looking for in the overview pages.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In most cases you will not need to import (and use) anything else than just rospy.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-02-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on 2012-02-23**:
had to import rospy.core.is_shutdown(). The API docs don't mention anything about rospy.is_shutdown().

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-02-23**:
rospy exports is_shutdown. You don't need to import rospy.core.

**Comment by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on 2012-02-23**:
@Lorenz Not trying to be pedantic, but if rospy exports 'is_shutdown', shouldn't that be explicitly mentioned in the api docs for rospy?

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-02-23**:
Using rospy.is_shutdown() as a loop condition is a very common idiom that you'll see if you look through the python tutorials.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-02-23**:
See Eric Perko's comment.  epydoc (the autodoc tool) is not capable of handling namespace remappings of symbols, which is why it lists 'is_shutdown' as 'rospy.core.is_shutdown'.  The rospy wiki page has a comprehensive overview of the public API.